# Org chart? - Is this possible with Microsoft graph API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

I am trying to build an organisation chart for SharePoint, however I can't seem to find any API calls on the graph explorer that would allow me to do so. Does anyone know if it is possible using graph API?

If not, does anybody know of any pre-built SPFx web parts that do this and are free?

Comment: Do you have a definitive requirement to use the graph api?  There is a pnp SPFx sample org-chart webpart that uses the SharePoint Rest API, not the Graph API: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-organisationchart.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards the sp-dev samples @willman however most of those samples don't work >.<

Comment: @willman If you can get it working let me know!